# Visual Studio Source Generator, generated source missing

Tags: visual-studio, sourcegenerators

I have been working on a source generator and it is going great. I can see the generated sources in the Analyzers menu.

```
-Proj
--Dependencies
---Analyzers
----MySourceGenerator
-----Source1
-----Source2
-----Source3
-----Source4
```

I can write code against the generated sources (as in invoke methods and create new instances of the classes). My issue is that Visual Studio is putting red squigglies under the class name with the below error.

```
The type of namespace Source1 could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My code complies and runs, but displays a ton of errors while I am developing. Is there a work around so that visual studio loads the sources?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 17.5.0 Preview 1.0